# YUI Carousel custom navigation

Tags: javascript, yui

Javascript Code

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function (ev) {
    var carousel = new YAHOO.widget.Carousel("container", {isCircular: true, numVisible:1});
    console.log(carousel.set('navigation', {prev: document.getElementById('prev'), next: document.getElementById('next')}));
    carousel.render();
    carousel.show();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
    <a href='#' ><span id='prev'> Prev </span></a> 
    <a href='#' ><span id='next'> Next </span></a> 
    <ol>
        <li><img src='history_base_files/200.jpeg' height="300" width="300" /></li>
        <li><img src='history_base_files/280.jpg' height="300" width="300" /></li>
        <li><img src='history_base_files/350.jpg' height="300" width="300" /></li>
        <li><img src='history_base_files/370.jpg' height="300" width="300" /></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Console outputs `false` on setting navigation property of carousel. Couldn't find any good reference online.

How to create yui carousel with custom navigation like anchor or span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question to report the solution worked for me

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
        <a id='prev' href="#" class="yui-carousel-button yui-carousel-prev" role="button"><span><strong>Prev</strong></span></a>
        <a id='next' href="#" class="yui-carousel-button yui-carousel-next" role="button"><span><strong>Next</strong></span></a>
        <ol>
            <li><a href='#'><img src='history_base_files/200.jpeg' height="300" width="300" /></a></li>
            <li><img src='history_base_files/280.jpg' height="300" width="300" /></li>
            <li><img src='history_base_files/350.jpg' height="300" width="300" /></li>
            <li><img src='history_base_files/370.jpg' height="300" width="300" /></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

Adding classes yui-carousel-button, yui-carousel-prev & yui-carousel-next to custom button element solved the issue.